# Show modal if value exists and show error message if not

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdo

Toggle is not exactly the term but, I want to check first if value is existing and then show my modal and if not the modal must not show and just a PHP error message.

What's happening now is, if the value doesn't exist the modal will show but when I refresh the present page my error message shows. 
This is my Jquery with my Ajax.

```
 $(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.cScanBtn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputQr = $('#scanQr').val();
    //console.log(inputQr);
    $('#inputBarcode').val(inputQr);
    location.reload();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'display_item.php',
        data: {
          inputQr:inputQr
        },
        success: function(result){
        //console.log(result);
        }
      });  
      $('#viewItem').modal('show');
  }); 
});
```

This is my Ajax file

```
<?php 

include 'includes/session.php';

$qr_code = $_POST['inputQr'];

$conn = $pdo->open();

    $checkQr = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS checkrows FROM product WHERE qr_code=:qr_code");

    $checkQr->execute(['qr_code'=>$qr_code]);

    $qr = $checkQr->fetch();

    if($qr['checkrows'] <= 0){  

        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Barcode doesn\'t exist! Kindly review your input!';

    }   

$pdo->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change your logic like,

```
 $(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.cScanBtn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputQr = $('#scanQr').val();
    //console.log(inputQr);
    $('#inputBarcode').val(inputQr);
    //location.reload(); // not required.
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'display_item.php',
        dataType:'json', // <--- we will get json response
        data: {
          inputQr:inputQr
        },
        success: function(result){
            // get the json response, and if the error status then show message in alert
            (result.status == 'error' && alert(result.message))
             || $('#viewItem').modal('show'); // or just show the modal
        }
      });  
  }); 
});
```

Now, in PHP change your code like,

```
<?php 
    include 'includes/session.php';
    $qr_code = $_POST['inputQr'];
    $conn = $pdo->open();
    $checkQr = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS checkrows FROM product WHERE qr_code=:qr_code");
    $checkQr->execute(['qr_code'=>$qr_code]);
    $qr = $checkQr->fetch();
    $response = array('status'=>'success','message'=>'Barcode exists'); // be positive here
    if($qr['checkrows'] <= 0){
        $msg = 'Barcode doesn\'t exist! Kindly review your input!';
        $_SESSION['error'] = $msg;
        $response = array('status'=>'error','message'=>$msg);
    }
    $pdo->close();
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Your logic is good and I understood it well. But still the modal is showing even if the barcode is not existing.